# How can I use ggtags as a company-mode backend?

Tags: completion, company-mode, gtags

I'm working on a project that doesn't play nice with clang. It also doesn't play nice with `ctags` because the `TAGS` file is ~180 MB and it chokes up whenever I do anything moderately intensive with it.

I have `ggtags` set up with it brilliantly, however, and I would like to force `company` to use only `ggtags` for completion. The [documentation](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) for the `ggtags` package says:

> `company` can use `ggtags` as completion source via `company-capf` which is enabled by default.

but I really have no idea what that means. How can I use the two together?

Comment: IIUC, It means that if `completion-at-point` uses ggtags's data to perform the completion, then company should automatically get to use ggtags as well (tho you may have to disable some other company backends for that, in case they take precedence).

Comment: @Stefan Okay, I think I follow and I'll give it a shot --- if you had time to write up a snippet of elisp to point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I don't know what might need to be written.  It depends on whether `completion-at-point` does get its data from ggtags, and whether company gets its data from elsewhere (and from where exactly, if so).